# Split Excel Text Strings by words

Tags: excel, vba

I have read through all the articles which are based around similar topics on here but haven't been able to use them to come up with a solution.

I have a column on my spreadsheet which I need to split into 3 separate columns, the problem is that the text in the cells are all of varying lengths. There are specific words which can be used to define where to split the cell but all the text in between these delimiters needs to also carry across.

For example I can use the words "Short", "Medium" and "Long" to define where to split the cell but all characters to the right of "Short" and before "Medium" would need to then carry across with "Short".

Does anyone have any VBA solutions for this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO!!! Post some representative data and an example of the goal. That will be very easy to understand.

Comment: How about a non-vba solution: Do a search-and-replace on your sheet to replace "short" with "~short" and "long" with "~long", etc. Then use Excel's Text to columns function using "~" as the delimiter.

Comment: As Naing said, you need to post a clear example.. maybe something like: "aaa short bbb medium ccc long ddd", then you need to explain how you want the output to be

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was trying to use text to columns before posting on here but it was removing all text after the delimiter. An example of the data would be Short aaaaaaaa Medium bbbbb Long ccc

Comment: Finally just to clarify, there are many cells with the data in this format but the amount of text between Short and Medium would be different in each cell.

Comment: @JamesSimpson Please specify the expected output for your -or my- example.

Answer (score 0):

```
strx = "testing this out short nathan test medium another test"
Debug.Print Mid(strx, 1, InStr(1, strx, "short") - 1)
```